# Is there a theoretical limit to how long an animal can live?

Tags: life, lifespan

I'm talking about potential life on other planets as well.

On earth, most animals live decades, and only a handful over 100 years. What has led to such a 'short' lifespan across the board?

Assuming there may be other carbon-based life forms similar to that of earth on other planets, would they also be limited to shorter lifespans, or is it possible to have a species that might live thousands of years, or even 100,000 or in extreme cases, a million years. Is there anything theoretical that might prevent this?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate to the linked question. It's asking specifically about a theoretical limit making organisms mortal. The evolution angle is just one type of answer, although that will be the coherent framework for talking about known life